# Sort array of integers

Tags: java, arrays, methods, integer

The problem I'm having with my program is when I print all the numbers, the 1st number I enter is duplicated twice and replaces the 2nd number

Ex. If i enter 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19 The output is 1,1,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19

How can I fix this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class InputSort_Integers
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Declarations
      final  int[] count = new int [10];

    // Scanner 
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Scanner Loop
    for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++)
    {

        System.out.print("Enter " + count.length + " numbers (Press enter after each entry): ");  
        count[i] = scanner.nextInt();       

    }

    // Print sorted number
    int sorted = printNumbers(count);                                                 

}

public static int printNumbers(int[] count)
{

    // Print loop
    for (int i=0; i<count.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(count[i]);
    // Sort Numbers
        Arrays.sort(count);

    }
 return count.length;
} 

}
```

Comment: It doesn't do that when I run it: http://ideone.com/SLds9F

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't `1,0,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19` that you entered?

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the first number then sorting from within the loop. You should sort the numbers once, before the loop begins. Change your `printNumbers` method to this:

```
public static int printNumbers(int[] count)
{
    // Sort Numbers
    Arrays.sort(count);

    // Print loop
    for (int i=0; i<count.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(count[i]); 
    }
    return count.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only call Arrays.sort once, not every pass through your loop. Corrected printNumbers:

```
public static int printNumbers(int[] count)
{
    // Sort Numbers
    Arrays.sort(count);

    // Print loop
    for (int i = 0; i < count.length; ++i)
    {
        System.out.println(count[i]);
    }

    return count.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `Arrays.sort(count);` inside your for loop, when you probably want to be calling it before the for loop instead. When I removed this line, it fixed the problem.